# Angular merge does not fire all observables within switchMap

Tags: angular

I am merging two observables in a switchMap operator but my problem is that only one observable fires. My code

```
    formArray.valueChanges
        .pipe(
            takeUntil( this._unsubscribeAll ),
            switchMap( sm => {
                const tempAnswerChanges$: Observable<any>[] = formArray.controls.map( ( c, i ) => {
                    return c.get( 'answer' ).valueChanges
                        .pipe(
                            tap( response => {
                                this.value = !this.value
                                formArray.controls[ 2 ].patchValue( { display: this.value }, { emitEvent: true } )
                                console.log(formArray.controls[ 2 ].value)
                            } ),
                        )
                } );
                const tempDisplayChanges$: Observable<any>[] = formArray.controls.map( ( c, i ) => {
                    return c.get( 'display' ).valueChanges
                        .pipe(
                            tap( response => {
                                console.log('Display Has changed',response)
                            } ),
                        )
                } );
                return merge(...tempDisplayChanges$, tempAnswerChanges$ );
            } ),
        ).subscribe();
```

In the example if the change the merge statement to

```
  return merge(...tempAnswerChanges$, tempDisplayChanges$ );
```

then the tempAnswerChanges$ fires and the tempDisplayChanges$ never fires. I don't understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
return merge(...tempAnswerChanges$, ...tempDisplayChanges$ );
```

Comment: Thanks - that works. Could you please explain why?

Comment: The three dots I added before tempDisplayChanges$ are the spread operator, (which you used in the correct way in the same line), it is commonly used to make copies of an array, or, in your case, mergin two. Please mark it as correct in order to help other people. I am glad it worked for you :D